# Rename all files in a directory by omitting last 3 characters

Tags: bash, grep, find, file-rename, mv

I am trying to write a bash command that will rename all the files in the current directory by omitting the last 3 characters. I am not sure if it is possible thats why I am asking here.

I have a lots of files named like this : `720-1458907789605.ts`

I need to rename all of them by omitting last 3 characters to obtain from `720-1458907789605.ts` ---> `720-1458907789.ts` for all files in the current directory.

Is it possible using bash commands? I am new to bash scripts.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native bash solution:

```
for f in *.ts; do
    [[ -f "$f" ]] || continue # if you do not need to rename directories
    mv "$f" "${f:: -6}.ts"
done
```

This solution is slow if you have really many files: star-expansion in `for` will take up memory and time.

Ref: [bash substring extraction](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

If you have a really large data set, a bit more complex but faster solution will be:

```
find . -type f -name '*.ts' -depth 1 -print0 | while read -d $\0 f; do
    mv "$f" "${f%???.ts}.ts"
done
```

Comment: I have a bash script like this:  location='/home/vod/canal3'

cd $location &&
  find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin +1 -type f -printf '%p\0%TF\0' |
    while IFS= read -rd '' file && read -d '' date; do
      mkdir -vp "$date" && mv "$file" "$date"
    done

Comment: it basically creates a folder, names it with current date, and then moves all the files to it. I need before moving or after to rename the file omitting the last 3 characters. How to implement your suggestion in this script?

Comment: Thank you. Last question, but if I would like to ignore first 3 characters I will write there ${???%file.ts}? I tried so and it didn't worked )

Comment: You should read the reference link I posted, there are many unobvious tricks with strings in bash. In short, you can use this construct: `${file:3}`. That is exactly the string named `file`, but without the first 3 characters.

Comment: ...and the string without the last 3 characters is `${file:: -3}` (note the space before minus, it is mandatory).

Comment: Not much, in fact. `${file:: -6}.ts` strips any 6 characters from the end of the string and then appends `.ts`. `${f%???.ts}.ts` strips any 3 characters and `.ts` from the end of the string (since we always must strip everything from some point to the end or to the beginning, we cannot strip just the middle of the string with operator `%`), and then appends back `.ts`.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. The changes you suggested worked (If i need to omit last 3 character ) `mv "$file" "$date/${file%???.ts}.ts"` But I tried the second variant (to omit first 3 character ) `mv "$file" "$date/${file: 3}"` and it outputs  incorrectly  ( it omits only the first character ). What is the problem ?) Thank you!

Comment: I think, something else is wrong. I tested omitting the first three characters and it works fine for me. But there is an alternative anyway (which I like less, but who cares :)): `${file#???}`. This means: strip three any characters from the beginning of the string (`#` means 'strip from the beginning', `?` means 'any character')

Comment: But if I want at the same time to omit first 4 character and last 3 character? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Combine the two ways (at least it works for me, bash 4.2.53). `${f:4: -3}`.

Comment: I tried your last command, it worked but partially) The funniest thing is that in order to omit first 4 and last 3 characters I needed to write this `${file:6: -6}.ts` this is strange but worked for me )

Answer (score 1):

With [Larry Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Wall)'s rename:

```
rename -n 's/...\.ts$/.ts/' *.ts
```

If everything looks okay remove dry run option `-n`.